# 'int' object is not subscriptable, ja testei várias vezes mas sempre que texto recebo essa mensagem

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def movinteiros(a):
    b=[]
    for i in a:
        if i=="c":
            b.append([-1,0])
        elif i=="b":
            b.append([1,0])
        elif i=="d":
            b.append([0,1])
        else:
            b.append([0,1])
    return b



opcao=int(input("Opcao de jogo:"))
n=int(input("Tamanho do tabuleiro:"))
matriz=[int(x) for x in input("Tabuleiro inicial:").split()]
```

Se as entradas forem:

```
1

2



1 2
3 0
```

ce

a função `trocapos` deveria devolver:

Comment: Aconselho que leia com atenção as diretrizes da comunidade de [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Essa entrada parece ser insuficiente para reproduzir o problema. Ao colocar as entradas citadas o programa ainda pede por "Movimentos".

Comment: Para essa entrada, `matriz` está ficando `[1, 2, [3, 0]]`. Ela deveria ser assim? Ou deveria ser `[[1, 2], [3, 0]]`?

Comment: deveria ser  [[1, 2], [3, 0]]

Comment: Se as entradas forem:

1

2  ce

1 2
3 0

Comment: Então deve ter percebido que a forma que gerou `matriz` não está correta.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro aparece por quê você está tentando usar um objeto que é um inteiro como se fosse uma lista ou um dicionário, usando colchetes após o mesmo - vamos supor que o objeto esteja na variável `x` - você ao programar supunha que x devia ter uma lista ou dicionário e escreveu `x[0]` ou `x["nome"]`, mas `x` na verdade contém um inteiro.

Então nesse caso aparece essa mensagem de erro, acompanhada da linha do erro. Como você não colocou a linha do erro, também não há motivo para alguém ficar executando seu programa de cabeça e procurar em que linha está - a informação está na sua tela.